# How to add table in Django admin without migrate command

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am using Django 1.10 when I use Django admin but I can not find my table in admin setting, because I just add my table by SQL but not use Django migrate what should I do to add some table in Django admin

I use @admin.register() in admin.py so I can see this in the setting because I am superuser
[it shows in admin index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDt1w.png)

but in User permissions settings it does not show 
because it does not in DB table auth_permission and some relative table
[empyt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4B9sZ.png)

Comment: can you post some code and explain a bit about what exactly you want to acheive?

Comment: define model and attach in admin

Comment: Define your `models` and do `migration` process. Then `register` the models in admin.py

Answer (score 3):

1. you should add in the file admin.py:

   ```
   from django.contrib import admin
   from .models import name_of_your_model
   ```

## Register your models here.

```
admin.site.register(name_of_your_model)
```

so you can see your tables created from the models in the administrator interface